# docker compose up - service can't communicate through http with dependant service ( gets 403 Forbidden )

Tags: docker-compose

I run `docker compose run serviceA` and have a dependant `serviceB`.

When trying to do an http call from `serviceA` to `serviceB` I get a 403 Forbidden.
Anyone knows why that is?

If I have the same setup but run a `docker compose up` the communication works fine.